# Is there any way in angular 6 to get ViewChildren deep?

Tags: angular

is there any way to get the children from a subcomponent?

Imagine the following component tree:

- App

  - Question

    - Question Option (contains a checkbox)
    - Question Option (contains a checkbox)
    - Question Option (contains a checkbox)

I want to access `Question Option` from `App` to check all checkboxes.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghvsuu for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in different way though.

Add `@ViewChildren(QuestionOptionComponent) options` in `QuestionComponent` instead of `AppComponent`

And in `AppComponent`

```
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild(QuestionComponent) question

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  checkAll() {
    console.log("this.question", this.question) // found
    console.log("this.options", this.question.options) // found

  }
}
```

Forked [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grcpgg)

Comment: This would require to know the exact structure beforehand which certainly isn't always the case. If some component does an ng-switch for example to display other components which also do ng-switch and we end up with an unknown structure it may still be desired to know which element are actually present

Answer (score 0):

**This code selects all items**
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kj7wv8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent {

    @ViewChild(QuestionComponent)
    private question: QuestionComponent;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    checkAll() {
        (<Array<QuestionOptionComponent>>this.question.options)
        .forEach( (item: QuestionOptionComponent) => {
            item.checked = true;
        });   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take an alternate and janky option by getting the App (or whatever component)'s native element by `constructor(private el: ElementRef){}`. Then in ngAfterViewInit do `setTimeout(() => { const myElements = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('[class="my-checkbox"]')});`

just replace the class="my-checkbox" with any identifying feature on the checkboxes (find it through chrome dev tools inspect element).

And use el.nativeElement instead of document because you don't want it to be global, you only want the ones that are child components.

It is very dirty method, but it will get you the html elements you need, regardless of how deep they are. It will not give you the angular components, but you should be able to update the checked state directly from the html.

If you have access to the question component, you should to an @viewchildren in there instead, I would only use this method as a last resort when working with a 3rd party library like Angular Material that you cannot edit the components directly.